# Collapse in Bootstrap 3 delaying on click even after changing transition timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There's a bootply with an example here: http://www.bootply.com/29mKfY3Vnf#

I'm trying to work with a collapsing function in Bootstrap, and everytime I click on the speaker header to expand the collapse, there is a short delay, and then the image appears and shifts the text down. I want to make this smoother. I think that the image is already loaded. I've tried changing the timing to a small number to approximate no transition(according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119906/turning-off-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-transition-animation/13829926#13829926) thread), but it doesn't seem to stick. Any idea what I could do? Much appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other way is to wrap your image and text in a div to collapse, instead two div to collapse.

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/Vq3K5JCvVb

**HTML** :

```
<h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".blonk">
    Speaker
</h3>
<div class="blonk collapse">
      <img class=" " src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhYwVULfg4p3BgWymiWNRUc_o05AHwhmT_ZaQG6u4iprAZ0jQJ">
     <div class=" " lang="sv">
          Kittens are beautiful     
     </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So you mean the effect could be queing? It's not super optimal since I've broken it up in two divs in different languages, so one of them is being filtered out but the image obviously remains.